# Open failed, E ACCESS permission denied?

Tags: java, android, permissions

We have encrypt a `external SD card File` from android.

When i was tried to encrypting a File, i got the error message as

`Open Failed! E-Access permission denied!`

How do solved this problem.

Error message Screenshot

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "chmod 777 " + strFromFilePath );` it does not provide any permission for my file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe missing

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

in your manifest?

Comment: Sorry, I am added already. My file permission as ----------. How to add permission through programmatically.

Comment: How is this external SD card connected to your device? What device is this? Post the code you use to determine the file path and open the file. Post more of your logcat.

Comment: I am so Sorry David. A USB device is connected to android tablet. USB path is /mnt/usbhost1. Some files are in the USB device. When i am tried to copy the content from one file to another file, i got the error message as `open failed: EACCESS (Permission denied). Thanks.

Comment: How did the files get on the USB device?

Comment: `File sdd = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getParentFile().getAbsolutePath());` to get the `/mnt` path and then manually select the `/mnt/usbhost1` path.

Comment: No, how did you write the files on the USB device? Also with this Android device? Or from a PC or whatever?

Comment: I am reading files from USB device and then create one new file to put all the existing file content.

Comment: My problem is some of the file permission as ----------. How to set permission as -rwxrwxrwx at runtime in android.

Comment: You can't do that (unless you are root). If the files have no permissions, then you don't have any permissions to change the permissions ;-) Put the device into a PC or a unix box and see if you can change the permissions.

Comment: Is it possible to change permission programmatically.

Comment: Sure. Look at these methods of the `File` class: `setReadable(), setWritable(), setExecutable()`. But you don't have permission to change the permissions ;-)

Comment: I already applied this metohd. Unfortunately this function is not worked for me. Any other solution.

Comment: As I said, you need to put the SD card in another computer and fix the permissions. That's all I can think of.